# Page loads but contents requested from the database are not show

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, bootstrap-4

I have written a blog web app with python, flask, mongodb and bootstrap. In my work if I select an article, The program must go into the database, find the corresponding ID of the selected article and should render the contents of the article to the html file a specified.
This is the sample of the code for the route:

```
# Home with articles displayed
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET','POST'])
def article():

    # Create Mongodb connection
    user = mongo.db.articles
    # Execute query to fetch data
    results = user.find() 

    # Iterate the data retrieved
    if results is not None:
        articles = results
        return render_template("index.html", articles=articles)
    else:
        msg = Markup("<h3>No Articles Posted.</h3>")
        return render_template("index.html", msg=msg)


# Single Article
@app.route('/home/<id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post(id):
    # Create Mongodb Connection
    user = mongo.db.articles
    # execute query
    article = user.find_one({'_id': id})

    return render_template("post.html", article=article)
```

This is also the code sample of the HTML file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} <title>Articles | Blog</title> {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <!-- Page Header -->
    <div class= "jumbotron">
        <h5>{{article.title}}</h5>
        <small>Written by Mr. Boss on {{article.date}} </small>
        <hr>
        <p class="lead">{{article.body}}</p>
      </div>


  <!-- Post Content -->

{% endblock %}
```

The page renders fine when I select the article but the problem is It does not render the information from the mongodb to the html file.
This the mongodb data in json:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c79d99195eded2364b03813"),
  "title":"Article One",
  "body":"This is the first article",
  "date":"2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Please, I am a beginner in python so take it easy on me if I am making any mistakes and help me solve this issue.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by:
1. importing `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`
2. changing the route to this:

```
# Single Article
@app.route('/home/<string:id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post(id):
    # Create Mongo Connection
    user = mongo.db.articles

    # execute query
    article = user.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})

    return render_template("post.html", article=article)
```